# Loop through a list with an autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of companies (listA, located in worksheet Workings2) and a list of companies(ListB - each company has multiple entries, located in worksheets data) with data attached, for list A i want to be able to take a company (in a cell in column B) and loop through listB on an Auto filter so that I can check if a certain column (AZ) has a certain count of values in a particular band (100,000-500,000). once I have the count of numbers I want to add it to a worksheet workings. After each company in ListB, I want to reset the filter and aplly the filter for the next company

I have the code below, which i have scrambled together, but it gives out a wacky number that makes no sense (in the order of 30,000, when I'm looking at around 100)

```
Sub calculate1()

Dim wsCriteria As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CompanyListLocation
Dim lr As Long, dlr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsCriteria = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
Set wsDest2 = Sheets("Workings2")

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = wsData.Range("B3: B418")

For i = 0 To 419

   With wsData.Rows(1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=i

lr = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
dlr = wsDest2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'wsData.AutoFilterMode = False

With wsData.Rows(1)
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Forward", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="NDF"
  If wsDest2.Range("C1:C" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count 
> 1 Then
  ff = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsData.Range("AZ:AZ"), ">" & 
100000, wsData.Range("AZ:AZ"), "<" & 500000)
wsDest2.Range("C3").Value = ff
     End If
.AutoFilter
End With
End With

Next i
End Sub
```

It would be amazing if anyone could help out

Comment: Why doesn't COUNTIFS work?

Comment: Hi, i don't think the issue is with the countifs, I think it is more to do with my loop. Which doesnt work, but not sure how to fix it

Comment: No, I mean get rid of your AutoFilter and just use COUNTIFS like `=sum(countifs(wsData.Range("AZ:AZ"), ">" & 
100000, wsData.Range("AZ:AZ"), "<" & 500000, wsData.Range("C:C"), {"forward", "ndf"}))`

Comment: Hi, but i need the auto filter as this filters each individual company and product (Forward and NDF), which is the granularity i need

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unclear on why this is not what you want to do. It seems a much more succinct solution. You need to add the company filter (e.g. `.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=i`) into the COUNTIFS to get the correct result. COUNTIFS is not filtered by .AutoFilter.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E:E, BB2, AZ:AZ, ">="&BC2, AZ:AZ, "<="&BD2, C:C, {"forward","ndf"}))
```

[image]